# Mimicking an audio waveform with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm making a visualisation showing the most common genres for concerts in a given city. Currently I'm displaying the data using a d3 area chart.

[image: data visualised using only area chart]

To make the visualisation more thematically appropriate I thought I'd try to make it look similar to an audio waveform, and this is where I hit a bit of a stumbling block.

Currently I'm still using the area chart mirrored over the x-axis, and this looks good for some cities when the data is spread out over a significant amount of time. It however doesn't look right when looking at a large city with lots of events.

Looks okay here:
[image: Dublin, Ireland]

Not so good here:
[image: London, UK]

I think what I want to do is to draw smaller rectangles inside the bounds of the area chart, first I thought I could use the area SVG as a mask, but then the tops of the rectangles would end up slanted...

Also thought of just making a bar chart with several bars for each data point, but that I think would result in big shifts in between each point. I want to still have the slants between data points that I get from an area/line chart.

Anyone got any suggestions? My goal would be to get the visualisation something like below:

[image: desired outcome - more details]

[image: desired outcome - less details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use data not for creating the chart, but for creating a jagged linear scale x -> y. Next, generate desired amount of rectangles, and map their indexes to x position. Rest is easy -- go over indexes, map them to x, map the gotten x to y, and you're set.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    
    var data = [{
      x: 1,
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: 5,
      y: 10
    }, {
      x: 15,
      y: 5
    }, {
      x: 20,
      y: 13
    }, {
      x: 25,
      y: 4
    }];
    
    var rectCount = 8;
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.x; }))
     .range(data.map(function(d){ return d.y; }));
    
    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
     .domain(d3.range(rectCount))
     .paddingInner(0.5)
     .range([d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.x; }),
              d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.x; })]);
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
     .attr('viewBox', '-5 -20 35 40');

    var chartData = d3.range(rectCount).map(function(i){
      var x = xScale(i);
      var width = xScale.bandwidth();
      var y = yScale(x);
      var height = y*2;
      return {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: width,
        height: height
      };
    });
    
    svg.selectAll('rect')
     .data(chartData)
    .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr('y', function(d) { return -d.y; })
     .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; })
     .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height; })

  </script>
</body>
```